# Why is Motoko Kusanagi usually the only one with thermoptic camouflage?

Tags: ghost-in-the-shell

I'm finally watching Stand Alone Complex and I expected more use of the technology, especially by Section 9 and underground groups who care not about the moral/legal reasons.

Is there a specific reason why these two groups do not use it all the time? Expense? Controlled substance?

Spoilers are ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking in the Stand Alone Complex Universe / series, **then no Kusnagi is not the only one who uses it**. We see Batou, the Tachikoma tanks, the Narcotics Suppression Squad (NSS), the elite JMSDF Black Ops unit Umibozu and even Togusa uses it in the series. In general, the other Section 9 members also use it indirectly when they are inside the Tachikoma tanks.

Example of Kusnagi, Batou and Togusa using it at around 1:08 (Episode 1 of SAC Season 1),

- YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAIcWoU117s
- Alternative Link: https://streamable.com/aslwo

An example of a Tachkikoma using it,

[image]

As for regarding it's usage, legality or possible limitations here's what the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_of_Ghost_in_the_Shell#Thermo-optical_camouflage) says,

> *An important technology used in the series is thermo-optical
>   camouflage (光学迷彩 kōgaku meisai). Members of Section 9 as well as their
>   Tachikoma tanks have the ability to activate a special camouflage
>   technology which enables them to blend in with the environment, making
>   them near-invisible across all visible spectrum and thermal imaging.
>   It is an active stealth system which projects ambient conditions of
>   the opposing side, thus rendering the masked object transparent by
>   transmission.*
>
> *The system is not perfect, as it seems unable to
>   compensate for sudden changes and physical impacts and not impervious
>   to close observation. It also has difficulty working in rain or if
>   walking through shallow water. A faint translucent distortion is shown
>   as the limitations of the technology. In the legal landscape of the
>   series, usage of the technology without a warrant is heavily
>   restricted. The use of this technology by Section 9 is the exception,
>   and not the norm - further highlighting their extraordinary legal
>   standing.*
>
> *In the Stand Alone Complex alternate timeline, however, this
>   technology seems to have been perfected and is capable of operating in
>   highly illuminated environment, as evidenced in the episode "Android
>   and I". The visual distortions are therefore purely for the benefit of
>   the viewers.*

Finally, in the Stand Alone Complex series, I suspect the reason why it appears that in Section 9 it's usually always only Kusnagi followed by Batou that use it more frequently is because they are usually the ones that are in the "offensive/dangerous part" of the operations or take in the solo offensive/assault operations. And this maybe due to their heavily cyberized / augmented bodies and their extensive military experience than the other members. Not saying that the other Section 9 members don't have their own specialties or quirks. They do and it's used for different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Mokoto is a pure android, a brain in a robot body, its been a while since i last watched it but i thing theirs only 2 other pure androids in all the series and films.

Its a feature of her android body, therefore while other may be highly augmented (i.e. Batou) they still have human components that means the tech simply wont work for them.

Comment: I doubt that would be the reason, as in the movie we see one of the suspected Puppet Masters use similar full-body optical camouflage, even though his body is at least mostly organic.